How to associate multiple texture files to downloaded model?
I'd like to get some help figuring out how to associate multiple texture files with a model. I downloaded a satellite model from the NASA's 3D Resource library and opened it in Blender, but it was not rendered with any texture information:

I somehow want to re-import all the texture information to render what it is supposed to look like:

This file contains a model file (TESS.blend) and a texture folder (textures) with several image files inside:

TESS_DIFF.png: Texture related to diffusive reflection?
TESS_SPEC.png: Texture related to specular reflection?
TESS_norm.png: Not sure what this is.
spec_power.png: Something related to specular reflection?
hardness.png: Not sure what this is.
foil_silver_ramp.png: Looks like the texture of a silver foil covering the aperture part.
foil_n.png: No idea what this is.

Unfortunately, there is not enough explanation on what each of the material files represent.
In the model file, I see some predefine material names in the Scene collection:

I first selecte TESS material under BUS>instruments> SolarPanel, and set its Base Color to TESS_DIFF.png and got the upper part of the solar panels rendered correctly:

I still need to import the texture for the aperture and the other side of the solar panels. I went to foil_silver material and assigned foil_silver_ramp.png to it, but the texture doesn't seem to be mapped correctly. I pressed U and ran smart UV mapping and got something like below:

In the object mode, the model looks like:

The mapping of the silver foil still doesn't look right. I also probably need to add the "uneven" texture of the foil in some ways, but not sure how. Can anyone direct me to a correct direction? I would appreciate any advice!
